# Combine different tables in a list in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

**update: Code below seems to work**

I'm not entire sure to how this question, so I apologise if this is worded badly. I tried looking for "combine different elements of a list using apply" but that doesn't seem to work.

Anyways, as the result of scraping a website, I have two vectors giving identifying information and a list that contains a number of different tables. A simplified version looks something like this:

```
respondents <- c("A", "B")
questions <- c("question1", "question2")

df1 <- data.frame(
   option = c("yes", "no"),
   percentage = c(70, 30), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(
   option= c("today", "yesterday"),
   percentage =c(30, 70), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df3 <- data.frame(
   option = c("yes", "no"),
   percentage = c(60, 40), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df4 <- data.frame(
    option= c("today", "yesterday"),
    percentage =c(20, 80), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

lst <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)
```

The first two tables are questions and responses from the first participant, and the second two tables are questions are from the second participant. What i would like to do is to create two tables that contain the answers to the questions for the two participants. So I would like something that looks like this:

```
question1 <- data.frame(
   option = c("yes", "no"),
   A = c(70, 30),
   B = c(60, 40), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

question2 <- data.frame(
   option = c("today", "yesterday"),
   A = c(30, 70),
   B = c(20, 80), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

In my case, I have 122 responses from 51 participants, and it ordered so that tables 1-122 are from the first participant, the next 122 tables are from the second participant, etc. Ultimately, then, I would like to have 122 tables (one table per question), with each table containing 51 columns that correspond to each participant. I am more or less at a loss as to how to do this, so I would appreciate any suggestions.

**This should now work**:

```
library("RCurl")
library("XML")

# Get the data
## Create URL address

mainURL <- 'http://www4.uwm.edu/FLL/linguistics/dialect/staticmaps/'
stateURL <- 'states.html'
url  <-  paste0(mainURL, stateURL)

## Download URL

tmp <- getURL(url)

## Parse
tmp  <-  htmlTreeParse(tmp, useInternalNodes = TRUE)

## Extract page addresses and save to subURL
subURL  <-  unlist(xpathSApply(tmp, '//a[@href]', xmlAttrs))


## Remove pages that aren't state's names
subURL  <- subURL[-(1:4)]


## Show first four states
head(subURL, 4)



#  Get questions 
## Select first state
suburl  <-  subURL[1]

## Paste it at the end of the main URL
url <- paste0(mainURL, suburl)


## Download URL
tmp  <- getURL(url)

## Read data from html 

tb <- readHTMLTable(tmp, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


##Remove empty strings
Questions  <- Questions[Questions!= '']


# Create objects to populate later

stateNames <- rep('', length(subURL))

## Populate stateNames

### Remove state_ from stateNames
stateNames <- gsub('state_','',subURL)

### Remove .html from stateNames
stateNames <- gsub('.html','',stateNames)

# Remove pictures in the data representing IPA symbols with their names      (e.g., names of the pictures)

## Get url
url <- paste0(mainURL, subURL)
tmp <- getURL(url) 

## Replace .gif with _
tmp <- gsub(".gif>", '_', tmp)

## Replace "<img\\s+src=./images/" with _
tmp <- gsub("<img\\s+src=./images/", '_', tmp)


# Read in data

tb <- readHTMLTable(tmp, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


## Subset 2nd and 4th columns and apply to every item on list
tb <-  lapply(tb, function(x) x[,c(2,4)])

## Remove quotation marks, percent sign and convert to number; apply to every item

tb <-  lapply(tb, function(x) {
  x [,2 ] = gsub('\\(','',x[,2] )
  x [,2 ] = gsub('%\\)','',x[,2])
  x [,2 ] = as.numeric(x[,2])
  x
}
)

## Assign column names to all dataframes
tb <- lapply(tb, setNames , nm = c("option", "percentage"))

#get rid of extra tables
tb1 <- tb[-seq(1, length(tb), by=123)] 

## Function to clean data sets

f1 <- function(list1){ Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by= 'option', all=TRUE), list1) }; res <- lapply(1:122, function(i) {indx <- seq(i, length(tb), by=122); f1(tb[indx])})

## Function to merge datasets together
res1 <- lapply(1:122, function(i) f1(tb1[seq(i, length(tb1), by=122)]))

## Create names for the states
stateNames2 <- c("option", stateNames)

# Rename columns in the new dataframes
res2 <- lapply(res1, setNames , nm = stateNames2)

# Test to see whether it works
test <- res2[[122]]
```

Comment: The example you provided is a simple one.  Can you make an example that mimics your dataset? (Just now I read the last part)

Comment: I added the actual problem I'm working with. I thought this might be too involved.

Comment: Here, in the update, do you need to merge `1` list element with `123`, something like `seq(1,length(tb), by=122)`, similary for `2` with 124, etc...

Comment: May be you can try `f1 <- function(list1){
     Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by= 'option', all=TRUE), list1)
   };  res <- lapply(1:51, function(i) {indx <- seq(i, length(tb), by=122); f1(tb[inx])})`

Comment: there are 122 responses from each of the 51 states. The data is little messy, since the first list element contains everything from that state. So responses from the first state are 2-123, responses from the second 125 to  246 (so, for just these two examples, 2 would merge with 123, 125 would merge with 246, etc.

Comment: Of course, getting rid of the first list element is easy (it just isn't in the code, and I have to run now). Thanks for the suggestion. I'm running it.

Comment: May be you subset the `tb` by `tb1 <- tb[-seq(1, length(tb), by=122)]; res1 <- lapply(1:51, function(i) f1(tb1[seq(i, length(tb1), by=122)]))`

Comment: Or may be the `res1 <- lapply(1:51, function(i) f1(tb1[seq(i, length(tb1), by=121)]))` as 1 element is removed

Comment: Thanks. This gives me something to work with. I haven't checked everything and I have to leave this for a bit, but it looks like it mostly worked, at least for first table (I need to do something with the column names. I needed to make some adjustments because the code for removing the unnecessary tables wasn't right (I put it in the code above)

Comment: If you were able to solve the problem, post the solution as an answer (not as an edit to your question) and then accept it. This marks your question as resolved and makes it clear to future users what worked.

Comment: I was wondering about whether I should wait for akrun to post the answer so I could mark his work as correct.

Comment: @JoeF It's okay to post the answer anyway there was some error in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to akrun (see comments), I got this to work. The full code is here:

```
library("RCurl")
library("XML")


# Get the data
## Create URL address



mainURL <- 'http://www4.uwm.edu/FLL/linguistics/dialect/staticmaps/'
stateURL <- 'states.html'
url  <-  paste0(mainURL, stateURL)
url

## Download URL

tmp <- getURL(url)

## Parse
tmp  <-  htmlTreeParse(tmp, useInternalNodes = TRUE)

## Extract page addresses and save to subURL
subURL  <-  unlist(xpathSApply(tmp, '//a[@href]', xmlAttrs))


## Remove pages that aren't state's names
subURL  <- subURL[-(1:4)]


## Show first four states
head(subURL, 4)



#  Get questions
## Select first state
suburl  <-  subURL[1]

## Paste it at the end of the main URL
url <- paste0(mainURL, suburl)


## Download URL
tmp  <- getURL(url)

## Read data from html 

tb <- readHTMLTable(tmp, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## Remove first column
Questions  <- tb[[1]][,1]


##Remove empty strings
Questions  <- Questions[Questions!= '']

# Create objects to populate later



 survey <-  vector(length(subURL), mode = "list")
i <- 1
stateNames <- rep('', length(subURL))



## Populate stateNames

### Remove state_ from stateNames
stateNames <- gsub('state_','',subURL)


### Remove .html from stateNames
stateNames <- gsub('.html','',stateNames)



# Remove pictures in the data representing IPA symbols with their names (e.g., names of the pictures)

## Get url
url <- paste0(mainURL, subURL)
tmp <- getURL(url) 


## Replace .gif with _

tmp <- gsub(".gif>", '_', tmp)

## Replace "<img\\s+src=./images/" with _

tmp <- gsub("<img\\s+src=./images/", '_', tmp)


# Read in data

tb <- readHTMLTable(tmp, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#tb <- tb[-1]


## Subset 2nd and 4th columns and apply to every item on list
tb <-  lapply(tb, function(x) x[,c(2,4)])


## Remove quotation marks, percent sign and convert to number; apply to every item

tb <-  lapply(tb, function(x) {
    x [,2 ] = gsub('\\(','',x[,2] )
    x [,2 ] = gsub('%\\)','',x[,2])
    x [,2 ] = as.numeric(x[,2])
    x
}
)


## Assign column names to all dataframes

tb <- lapply(tb, setNames , nm = c("option", "percentage"))

## Remove unneeded dataframes in list

tb1 <- tb[-seq(1, length(tb), by=123)]


## Function to clean data sets

f1 <- function(list1){ Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by= 'option', all=TRUE), list1) }; res <- lapply(1:122, function(i) {indx <- seq(i, length(tb), by=122); f1(tb[indx])})

## Function to merge datasets together
res1 <- lapply(1:122, function(i) f1(tb1[seq(i, length(tb1), by=122)]))

## Create names for the states
stateNames2 <- c("Options", stateNames)

# Rename columns in the new dataframes
res2 <- lapply(res1, setNames , nm = stateNames2)

# Test to see whether it works
test <- res2[[1]]
```